# Make a Mysql query that finds data just before another (in RoR)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm making this query to MySql

```
Image.find( :all,
     :conditions => ["created_at > ? && approved = 1", @image.created_at],
                            :order => "created_at DESC", :limit => 5)
```

However, I want the images create *just before* the given image was created at. Right now, it's returning a list of images from the top of the list, that were create much, much before that image. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your current query will find any images newer than @image because your using >. You'll need to decide what kind of range you're wanting to look in.. What time frame do you consider "just before"? Minutes? Seconds?

To find all images created within 5 mins of @image, try:

```
Image.find(:all, :conditions => ["(created_at > ? and created_at < ?) and approved = 1", @image.created_at.advance(:minutes => -5), @image.created_at])
```

Comment: Well, let's say there are four objects created in this order: {img1, img2, img3, img4} ... then if I do the query on img2, then I want {img3, and img4] to be returned in that order... in other words, the ones created immediately after the obj, in the order they were created.

Comment: Oh right, sorry, I misread it. In that case, setting the order to "created_at asc" will do it. (asc is the default, so you could clean it up to just "created_at" if you wanted to)

Answer (score 0):

My solution feels more like a hack, but I'm not sure of a better one. I set :order => "created_at ASC"... and then reversed the resulting array, and got the response I wanted. Hrm.